# ExifInterface always return 0 Orientation

Tags: android, picasso, android-bitmap

I see many questions about that but i don't have found an answer to my issue.

I try to display an profil image that can be captured with the camera or loaded from the storage.

I use ExifInterface to determine the right rotation for Picasso which load images.

I don't understand why for all pictures there is an orientation = 0

[image]

Below my code, very simple :

```
 private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);


    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("file:" + destination.getPath()).rotate(MyTools.getFileExifRotation("file:" + destination.getPath())).into(avatar);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    Uri uri=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            uri=data.getData();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    try {
        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("file:" + uri.getPath()).rotate(MyTools.getFileExifRotation("file:" + uri.getPath())).into(avatar);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 public static int getFileExifRotation(String path) throws IOException {
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);
    int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return 90;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return 180;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return 270;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I test on a LG G4 phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bitmap. Bitmaps do not contain orientation. After that you compress the bitmap to a .jpg. That will not add an orientation or an exif header.

So it is useless to use ExifInterface for that .jpg. Or to try to get the orientation.

You know you are saving a thumbnai!? Use the original instead.

Comment: You right i worked on the bitmap i change the code to get exif information directly after the : private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        try {
            thumbnail=Tools.rotateImageIfRequired(thumbnail, data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Still not working ExifOrientation equal 0. I need this to display an avatar.

Comment: Unclear why you tampered with your code. It's still a bitmap that you begin with. And even the same bitmap as before. Bitmaps do not contain exif or orientation information so all makes no sense. What you have to do instead i already said.

Comment: How can we get the exif information of a jpeg image then? Or in other words how can we save an image in jpeg and also preserve its exif orientation data.

Comment: `How can we get the exif information of a jpeg image then? `. What is a jpg image? I only know jpg files. For a jpg file use `getFileExifRotation()` function from this post.

Comment: `Or in other words how can we save an image in jpeg and also preserve its exif orientation data`. Those are not other words but something completely different. Moreover its unclear with what kind of image you start. Whats image?